# Gradle-sync showing Gradle project sync in progress after adding firebase sdk dependencies

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add the Firebase dependencies to my build.gradle(module) file but it is showing that the Gradle project sync is in progress.

I have already downloaded Google Play Services in the the Android SDK:

```
tools-> sdk manager-> android sdk-> sdk-tools -> google play services
```

I have also tried adding: `mavencentral()` in place of `jcenter()`.

build.gradle(module) : https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/1329/mOe2gG.png
build.gradle(project) : https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/7752/1UOjLt.png

After running for about 40 minutes it is throwing the following error:

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:[16.5.0].

Comment: Try `Invalidate Caches and Restart`

Comment: @Yupi I have tried Invalidate cache/restart. It still won't work

Answer (score 0):

Modify module(build.gradle) to include measurement-sdk-api.

```
dependencies {
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:17.0.0
}
```